# Highlight only the search word in Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel, highlight

Am working on search word highlight in excel. The search words are kept in an xml file. The code below highlights the whole cell instead of just highlighting that particular word.

Where am i going wrong? I need to just highlight the search word in a cell and not the whole cell(all the words in the cell).

```
try
{
    string[] arr = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\273714\Desktop\Dictionary.xml").Descendants(nodeString).Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();

    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;

    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
    Excel.Range range;
         xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)doc1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Excel.Range last = xlWorkSheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
    range = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", last);
   // range = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1", "A100");

    //Do your search thing here

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
        {
            str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
            if (str == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("null");
            }
            else
            {
                str.Replace("\\", "");
                string[] words = str.Split(' ');
                foreach (string arrs in arr)

                {
                   foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                        if (word == arrs)
                        {
                            var cell = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range);

                            cell.Font.Bold = 1;
                            cell.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You tell us? Are you getting an error? is anything happening? Questions must **describe the specific problem**

Comment: have mentioned it above. Am not getting any error. I need just the word to get highlighted . but the whole cell where the word is found is getting highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

According to that all the letters in the cell are highlighted. I think you want to highlight only the text in cell you searched.
You can follow this

```
Excel.Range val = xlWorkSheet.Cells[18, "C"] as Excel.Range;
string match = "find";
string match2 = val.Value2.ToString();
int index=-1;
//Here apply  string  matching to find index of first letter of matching sub string 
// if the index is not -1  then do following      
            val.get_Characters(index, match.Length).Font.Color =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```